# Symfony2 assetic dump for prod mode fails

Tags: symfony, assetic

When I try to dump my JS and CSS assets with assetic

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

instead of creating the files I, it outputs the content of the to-be-dumped JS file on my screen (in the console window).

What is wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: Look inside you composer and find which version of `assetic` you have installed. Maybe it's a known bug and you need to update it...

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not it: I'm using v2.3.0, which is (currently) the latest release.

Comment: OK, maybe you have set some assetic filter that fails? What is the value of `assetic.write_to` value in your config(_dev).yml?

Comment: The `write_to` parameter is not set, neither in my `config.yml`, nor in my `config_dev.yml` file.

Comment: Try setting both `read_from` and `write_to` values to: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"

Comment: Still the same behaviour :(

Comment: Weird :-/ Oh well, maybe it's time to start digging through Assetic command files and determining why and when output goes to console... :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39410/discussion-between-gottlieb-notschnabel-and-jperovic)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I just needed to install java

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

you can also look on the begining of output, this might help:

```
app/console assetic:dump > outfile 2>&1
```